# WordPress default number of results returned

Tags: wordpress

For some reason this query is only returning the 10 most recently published results, there should be at least 15 or so. So my question is, if I don't specify the number of results in my query, will WordPress default to 10 or something?

```
<?php getGallery('test', 'test2'); ?>


function getGallery($galleryLink, $altLink){

    global $post;

    // search for any pages with a custom field of 'test'
    query_posts('meta_key='.$galleryLink.'&post_type=page');

    if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, $galleryLink, true); 
        $alt = get_post_meta($post->ID, $altLink, true);
        $permalink = get_permalink($id);?>

    <a href='<?php echo $permalink ?>'><img src="<?php echo $link ?>" alt="<?php echo  $alt ?>"/></a>

    <?php endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default number of returned posts in $wp_query is defined in Dashboard > Settings > Reading. There you have defined 10, but remember that other people can set diffrent number on their blogs.

i hope you know that if you want to define your own number of posts you should add posts_per_page=X to query :) if you want to always return all posts matched to query put -1 in place of X

Comment: Brilliant - that's what I needed to know; how to override the user setting. Thanks v much for pointing this out in the dashboard too, I didn't know you could set this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The standard [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) query shows the number of posts defined in your Reading Settings page in WordPress, which defaults to 10.

See the examples under "Pagination Parameters" in [the WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you want to alter this programatically, rather than relying on the setting. For example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1' );
```

...will retrieve all posts.

Comment: Nice call on the "infinity" flag.

Comment: Yes, I marked you up - that was what I needed - thanks for the infinity flag!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the default value of 10 to any number you specify with the `posts_per_page` parameter in the query, like so:

```
query_posts('meta_key='.$galleryLink.'&post_type=page&posts_per_page=20');
```

Sub in any value you like instead of 20.  Better yet, use a variable and stay away from literals.

Comment: Great point about putting in a variable rather than a literal, not sure how I would do this with the example though - basically the variable would be however many it could find, but that would create a loop wouldn't it?

Comment: I ended up using -1 as infinity in the end as per @mattgibson's suggestion

Comment: Sounds like the perfect fit in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your default loop, just go to Settings --> Reading and change "Blog pages show at most" to your desired number.  If you specify a number that is less than your total amount of posts you'll have to include some sort of navigation to allow the visitor to go previous posts.